# 'pandas.core' has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, qgrid

I want to use qgrid to test a machine learning model interactively. However when loading my dataframe into qgrid I have an error with the dataframe I'm loading:

```
import qgrid
import pandas

# Import a CSV file and display it as a Qgrid widget
df_test = pd.read_csv('out.csv', engine='python', encoding='utf-8')
qgrid_df = qgrid.show_grid(df_test)
qgrid_df
```

Indeed, it returns:

```
'pandas.core' has no attribute 'index'
```

Do you know how I can handle this issue?

Comment: Known compatibility issue, see [here](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid/issues/287).

Comment: @AlexanderEjbekov Thanks! So I should modify `grid.py`. But how do I do that if I pip installed this library?

Comment: I would suggest upgrading/downgrading instead. If you do need to patch it yourself, you need to find it's location on your disk. This is not recommended however, because any update could potentially brake your code.